# How to make a button circular

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button which I am trying to make a perfect circle. I currently have used the code:

```
 startButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
 startButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.frame.width/2
```

But as you can see in the photo, the circle drawn in imperfect and cutting off some of the text.[image]

Width and Height are equal.[image]

Comment: make the button width equals to height,

Comment: In addition to what @aircraft wrote, do not use a corner radius. Instead, use a mask view / layer.

Comment: Width and Height are equal

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If yes what are the constraints that you have set to the button>

Comment: Yes I am, is that affecting the code?

Comment: Have you set the width and height constraints?

Comment: Ah... yes I have. Removing the constraint has fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: you need to make cornerRadius in layoutSubviews() {} and its shoul working with constraints also